# Hydra - Specifying config group with a keyword other than the directory

Tags: fb-hydra

Say I have the following file structure:

```
|--configs
|  |--config.yaml
|  |--A
|     |--conf1.yaml
|     |--conf2.yaml
|     |--conf3.yaml
|--main_app.py
```

and my base config.yaml looks like

```
defaults:
  A: conf1
```

If I want to run some other config like conf2 or conf3, I can simply run

```
python main_app.py A=conf2
```

What I am trying to do is to somehow use a different keyword from the directory name to specify this config above. For example,

```
python main_app.py B=conf2
```

For reasons I can't explain, it is not possible for me to change the directory name from A to B. However, I would find the behavior I described above desirable since B is a way more descriptive keyword than the directory name A. Is something like this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux you can create a symbolic link.
Hydra itself does not support this.